# simple install drupal in subfolder

Tags: drupal

This seems like it should be simplpe so if someone has a link that answers this I'll be happen with that and if this should be posted somewhere else please let me know.

### **What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to install Drupal in a sub folder, and just have it work in the sub folder.
www.example.com/drupal/ so when i go to www.example.com/drupal/ i'll see the install.

### **The issues**

All I get is a blank white screen not 
I have changed the .htaccess files
adding
RewriteBase /drupal

I have tried reinstalling everything but still just a blank white screen.
there is no .htaccess file in the root directory.

**Any help or links would be appreciated**, I have been looking for a step by step or common issues but all the links I found are about rewrite the .htaccees so the sub directory is the main site or moving a site live.

Thanks

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow always something simple, the server was set with php4 I had to move it to another server.
this took me 2 days to notice this.

so if you have a white screen make sure you check your php settings ;)